# AWS Lambda Function Issue with Slack Webhook

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops

I'm using the AWS lambda function to send alerts to our slack channel. But, due to some unknown issue, I'm not getting slack alert and not even getting any kind of error message from the AWS lambda function. Logs represent that the function ran successfully without any error but I do not receipt any alert

code:

```
import json, sys, csv, os
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     def Send2Slack(message):
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                print('inside slack function')
                url = "webhook_URL"
                title = (f"New Incoming Message")
                slack_data = {
                    "username": "abc",
                    "channel" : "xyz",
                    "attachments": [
                        {
                            "color": "#ECB22E",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "title": title,
                                    "value": message,
                                    "short": "false",
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
                byte_length = str(sys.getsizeof(slack_data))
                headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Content-Length': byte_length}
                response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(slack_data), headers=headers)
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    
   output = "Hello Slack "
   Send2Slack(output)
```

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong and help me fix this issue.

Comment: have you added a log to check what the response you are getting back is? Just because its 200 does not mean it did what you wanted. 200 is 'we successfully got your message and were able to respond' - that response can (and often is!) a failure message that isn't a complete failure - if for instance your channel name was not able to be found then it might return 200 - channel does not exist.

Comment: Could you please help me, how can I add the log to check what's the response is? Also, I'm running the same script locally without using the lambda function and I'm getting a slack alert. I feel there is sometimes with this lambda_handler function only. Please help me troubleshoot.

Comment: If your not getting `inside slack function` written to your logs, try indenting `def Send2Slack(message):` so its at the same level as `output = "Hello Slack"`. I think Lambda is seeing an empty `lambda_handler`. (just a guess/not a python programmer). FYI slack returns a 404 for `channel_not_found` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to answer this issue.

```
def Send2Slack(message):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Once I removed `if __name__ == '__main__':` from `send2slack` function the it worked.

Otherwise, I was not able to get into the function.
Thanks for all your help.